# Staging Info.plist doesn't exist with react-native-config

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-config

My React Native use react-native-config for dev, staging and prod environment setup. While running `pod install` on `ios` folder, I got:

```
[!] The plist file at path `/Users/baguzzzaji/Projects/Logique/HIB/ios/Users/baguzzzaji/Projects/Logique/HIB/ios/HIBStaging-Info.plist` doesn't exist.
```

The file is exist but there's a repeated path and I couldn't find the line which set the path on Podfile. How do I fix the path issue with the correct path?